# ambiguous call to 2 parents method

Tags: c++, oop

I want to call display method in main by C object. but it is ambiguous
as display is in both A and B class. I think making it virtual will not help too.

```
class A { 
public: 
    A()
    { 
        cout << "A's constructor called" << endl;
    }
    void display()
    {
        cout << "A display" << endl;
    }
};

class B { 
public: 
    B() 
    { 
        cout << "B's constructor called" << endl; 
    }
    void display()
    {
        cout << "B display" << endl;
    }
}; 

class C : public A, public B // Note the order 
{ 
public: 
    C() 
    { 
        cout << "C's constructor called" << endl; 
    } 

    
};
```

Comment: You can use a qualified name.

Comment: `C c; c.A::display();`

Answer (score 1):

You just need to tell the compiler which `display` you want to call. To call `B`s:

```
int main() {
    C c;
    c.B::display();
}
```

However, I would argue that your design is flawed. Why does `C` inherit two different `display`?

Comment: This was sample just to test this problem.

Comment: @UsamaJaved and? The problem is that `C` inherits two different `display`. example or not, you should fix the design ;)

Answer (score 0):

In such a case use a qualified name. For example

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A { 
public: 
    A()
    { 
        cout << "A's constructor called" << endl;
    }
    void display()
    {
        cout << "A display" << endl;
    }
};

class B { 
public: 
    B() 
    { 
        cout << "B's constructor called" << endl; 
    }
    void display()
    {
        cout << "B display" << endl;
    }
}; 

class C : public A, public B // Note the order 
{ 
public: 
    C() 
    { 
        cout << "C's constructor called" << endl; 
    } 

    
};

int main() 
{
    C c;
    
    c.A::display();
    c.B::display();
    
    return 0;
}
```

Another way is to use a casting like for example

```
static_cast<A &>( c ).display();
```

Pay attention to that it is better to make the member function display a constant member function like for example

```
    void display() const
    {
        cout << "B display" << endl;
    }
```